DynamicReports subreport toimage got width=-1
      DRDataSource callDataSource = new DRDataSource("topK", "userId", "seatId", "usage");
      DRDataSource textDataSource = new DRDataSource("topK", "userId", "seatId", "usage");
      StyleBuilder borderStyle = Styles.style()
          .setBorder(Styles.border(Styles.pen(1f, LineStyle.SOLID)))
          .setHorizontalTextAlignment(HorizontalTextAlignment.CENTER);
      var topK = col.column("Top k", "topK", type.integerType())
          .setTitleStyle(stl.style(stl.fontTimesNewRomanBold()).setHorizontalTextAlignment(HorizontalTextAlignment.CENTER))
          .setStyle(borderStyle);
      var userId = col.column("User Id", "userId", type.longType())
          .setStyle(borderStyle)
          .setTitleStyle(stl.style(stl.fontTimesNewRomanBold()).setHorizontalTextAlignment(HorizontalTextAlignment.CENTER));
      var seatId = col.column("Seat Id", "seatId", type.longType())
          .setStyle(borderStyle)
          .setTitleStyle(stl.style(stl.fontTimesNewRomanBold()).setHorizontalTextAlignment(HorizontalTextAlignment.CENTER));
      var usage = col.column("Usage", "usage", type.integerType())
          .setStyle(borderStyle)
          .setTitleStyle(stl.style(stl.fontTimesNewRomanBold()).setHorizontalTextAlignment(HorizontalTextAlignment.CENTER));
      JasperReportBuilder callMonthlySubReport = report()
          .title(cmp.text("Top %d Usage - %s".formatted(LIMIT, CALL)).setStyle(stl.style(stl.fontTimesNewRoman().boldItalic())))
          .setPageFormat(PageType.A4)
          .columns(topK, userId, seatId, usage)
          .setDataSource(callDataSource);
      JasperReportBuilder textMonthlySubReport = report()
          .title(cmp.text("Top %d Usage - %s".formatted(LIMIT, TEXT)).setStyle(stl.style(stl.fontTimesNewRoman().boldItalic())))
          .setPageFormat(PageType.A4)
          .columns(topK, userId, seatId, usage)
          .setDataSource(textDataSource);
      DRDataSource monthDataSource = new DRDataSource("month", "call", "text", "bill");
      TextColumnBuilder<String> monthCol = col.column("Month", "month", type.stringType())
          .setStyle(borderStyle)
          .setTitleStyle(stl.style(stl.fontTimesNewRomanBold()).setHorizontalTextAlignment(HorizontalTextAlignment.CENTER));
      TextColumnBuilder<Integer> callCol = col.column("Call", "call", type.integerType())
          .setStyle(borderStyle)
          .setTitleStyle(stl.style(stl.fontTimesNewRomanBold()).setHorizontalTextAlignment(HorizontalTextAlignment.CENTER));
      TextColumnBuilder<Integer> textCol = col.column("Text", "text", type.integerType())
          .setStyle(borderStyle)
          .setTitleStyle(stl.style(stl.fontTimesNewRomanBold()).setHorizontalTextAlignment(HorizontalTextAlignment.CENTER));
      TextColumnBuilder<BigDecimal> billCol = col.column("Bill", "bill", type.bigDecimalType())
          .setStyle(borderStyle)
          .setTitleStyle(stl.style(stl.fontTimesNewRomanBold()).setHorizontalTextAlignment(HorizontalTextAlignment.CENTER));
      JasperReportBuilder sixMonthSubReport = report()
          .title(cmp.text("Six Month Usage").setStyle(stl.style(stl.fontTimesNewRoman().boldItalic())))
          .setPageFormat(PageType.A4)
          .columns(monthCol, callCol, textCol, billCol)
          .summary(
              cht.lineChart()
                  .setCategory("month", String.class)
                  .series(cht.serie(callCol), cht.serie(textCol), cht.serie(billCol))
                  .setCategoryAxisFormat(cht.axisFormat().setLabel("Month"))
                  .setValueAxisFormat(cht.axisFormat().setLabel("Usage"))
          )
          .setDataSource(monthDataSource);
      FileOutputStream outputStream = new FileOutputStream("/Users/moatable/Desktop/test.jpg");
      report()
          .pageHeader(cmp.text("Usage Report").setStyle(stl.style(stl.fontTimesNewRomanBold())))
          .pageFooter(cmp.pageXofY())
          .setPageFormat(PageType.A4)
          .setPageMargin(margin(20))
          .title(cmp.text("Monthly Usage Report - %s".formatted(month)).setStyle(stl
              .style(stl.fontTimesNewRomanBold())))
          .detail(cmp.verticalList(
              cmp.subreport(callMonthlySubReport),
              cmp.subreport(textMonthlySubReport),
              cmp.subreport(sixMonthSubReport)
          ))
          .toImage(outputStream, ImageType.JPG);

java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Width (-1) and height (842) cannot be <= 0
    at java.desktop/java.awt.image.DirectColorModel.createCompatibleWritableRaster(DirectColorModel.java:1016)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.image.BufferedImage.<init>(BufferedImage.java:324)
    at net.sf.dynamicreports.jasper.builder.JasperReportBuilder.toImage(JasperReportBuilder.java:548)
    at net.sf.dynamicreports.jasper.builder.JasperReportBuilder.toImage(JasperReportBuilder.java:487)
    at com.dialer.server.schedule.DailyUsageReportSchedule.main(DailyUsageReportSchedule.java:327)

I tried to use the above code to generate a report, but it told me that width=-1.These three reports can be exported normally. But when I combine them, I get an error. I debugged and found that the topage of the report was 0.
The length of the pages obtained here is 0,
if (toPage == null) {
      toPage = jasperPrint.getPages().size();
    }

I looked up this problem and didn't find a solution.
